# Instantiate moving objects next to each other

Tags: unity

I am trying to find the correct time to spawn my object. If my object moves one unit per second, how long should I wait before spawning my other object so it be ass to ass to the other object? I tried waiting for one second in my coroutine before instantiating the object but there is a small gap.

Comment: If your unit moves one unit per second, then after one second it is one unit away from the spawn point. If that's too much, then it sounds like your object is less than one unit long — but you haven't told us what size it actually is.

Comment: My quad is indeed 1 unit long. Maybe it is a time thing? The gap is like 0.03. I tried running it in FixedUpdate but same thing. Perhaps I should round my time? So instead of doing transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime I could somehow round the time

Comment: How are you measuring out your spawn interval time, or advancing your objects to adjust for the difference in time between the desired spawn and the time the frame is actually being evaluated?

Comment: I just divided distance by speed to get time. So 1/1 = 1

Comment: No, I mean edit your question to show us the code you're using to spawn the objects at the appropriate time.

Comment: I literally have 15 objects already spawned at Start and they start moving immediately since each quad has a script that has an update that runs the code I showed you above and that is it. Then in my GameManager I have a coroutine that instantaites a quad at z 14 every 1 second (trying to catch those 15 quads as they move)

Comment: Yep, that's the code I'm asking you to add to your question. This site works a lot faster when you add all the relevant code as early as possible.